# Firebase How to display the right child value in another viewController when click a button

Tags: swift, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, marker

I need some help, I'm new on Swift and Firebase.

I have a GoogleMaps with some markers on the FirstViewController.
A marker is an event, and each event has an owner user, the owner has a name.
When any other user click on a marker on the map he can choose between see the event or see the user profile of the owner who posted that marker on the map.

But the issue is I can't find how to display the right profile of the clicked marker.
Someone can help me?

This is my Firebase Database for Markers:
[image]

And this is what happen when a user click on a marker on that map:
[image]

If I choose "See profile" button, then this is the UserViewController which display the following image. You can see the name "Patricsme" for the user owner of the marker but this is not this one I choose to see (I chosen the "DragonGiggs" name you can see that on the second photo, and this is the name of the data of Firebase I post it.

[image]

So my question is how can I show in the UserViewController the right name of this marker?

I try to do it with this code but can't work:

```
func seeProfile(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profile") as! UserViewController

    let usersRef = ref.child("markers")
    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
            print("No data")
        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let userSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let uid = userSnap.key
                let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let name = userDict["nom"] as! String
                vc.name.text = name
                let key = userDict["key"] as! String
                vc.numRoom = key
                let photo = userDict["photoURL"] as! String
                vc.photoURL = photo
                let titre = userDict["titreEvent"] as! String
                vc.titre = titre
            }
        }
    })
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I put this function here:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "See profile", style: .default, handler: self.consulterProfil))
```

This code always find the last data on my Firebase database, I can't find a way to solve this issue.

Here's the UserViewController:

```
class UserViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel! // pseudo
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView! // userImg

var ref: DatabaseReference!
var photoURL: String!
var room: Room!
var numRoom: String!
var titre: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: photoURL)
    ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Impossible de télécharger l'image depuis Firebase car \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if let imgData = data {
                if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.image.image = img
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.image.reloadInputViews()
    }
}
}
```

Other issue the photo can't display on the imageView.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No one know what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're presenting your User Profile View Controller outside of your firebase callback. In other words the data in your call to `usersRef.observeSingleEvent` hasn't been returned before the profile is being displayed. Try changing it to -

```
func seeProfile(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profile") as! UserViewController

    let usersRef = ref.child("markers")
    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
        print("No data")
    } else {
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let userSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let uid = userSnap.key
            let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            let name = userDict["nom"] as! String
            vc.name.text = name
            let key = userDict["key"] as! String
            vc.numRoom = key
            let photo = userDict["photoURL"] as! String
            vc.photoURL = photo
            let titre = userDict["titreEvent"] as! String
            vc.titre = titre
        }
    }
    // This needs to be inside the callback
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

You may also want to move it inside your `if` statement just in case the profile isn't returned.